# Taking hash input in an API - Python Flask

Tags: python-2.7, rest, api, flask

I am a beginner in making API. I have followed the blog https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask and able to create the Get - Post API method.

I am using Flask to making Rest API. Please see the code below in which I want to take question as input in API and return an answer in JSON format by making my code as an API.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/match/api/v1', methods = ['POST'])
def my_form_post():
if not request.json or not 'question' in request.json:
    abort(400)
input_text_p = request.json['question'] # access input from curl request
reference_data = request.json['data'] # to access data field from the API         request
path = 'airtel_faq.xlsx'
question_list, answer_list = read_excel_file(path) # reading some reference data from an excel file
input_text = input_text_p.translate(None, string.punctuation) # remove punctuation

final_answer = find_similarity(input_text, answer_list, question_list)
print "Final Answer is : ", final_answer

values = [
{'id' : 1,
 'answer' : final_answer # answer I want in JSON
 'done' : False
}
]
return jsonify({'values': values}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug = True)
```

I am running my script on local machine and making the curl request as:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"input_question":"I want to check my internet plan", "data":"{"q":"haha","a":"wawa"}","type":"1"}"}' http://localhost:5000/match/api/v1
```

My question is can I pass **"data":"{"q":"haha","a":"wawa"}"** as input to the API using curl, as the q and a in the data will be the related set of question and asnwer. Please let me know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be http://localhost:5000/match/api/v1,  but you put two '/' between "5000" and "match"